# How to deal with "%1" in the argument of QString::arg()?

Tags: qt, string-formatting, placeholder, qstring

Everybody loves

```
QString("Put something here %1 and here %2")
    .arg(replacement1)
    .arg(replacement2);
```

but things get itchy as soon as you have the faintest chance that `replacement1` actually contains `%1` or even `%2` anywhere. Then, the second `QString::arg()` will replace only the re-introduced `%1` or both `%2` occurrences. Anyway, you won't get the literal `"%1"` that you probably intended.

Is there any standard trick to overcome this?

If you need an example to play with, take this

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    qDebug() << QString("%1-%2").arg("%1").arg("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

This will output

```
"foo-%2"
```

instead of

```
"%1-foo"
```

as might be expected (not).

```
    qDebug() << QString("%1-%2").arg("%2").arg("foo");
```

gives

```
"foo-foo"
```

and

```
    qDebug() << QString("%1-%2").arg("%3").arg("foo");
```

gives

```
"%3-foo"
```

Comment: I know, I could just use string concatenation using `operator + ()` but in some places, e.g. translation using `tr()`, one would like to keep the ability to reorder the arguments in the template.

Comment: Wow! I never encountered that case, but if a translation is the string "%1" (opposed to 1%, for example) then it won't work right at all. This really does not make sense. It looks like they reapply the arguments to the result over and over.

Comment: Wasn't there the possibility to pseudo-escape "%1" by writing "%%1"?  Still the functionality of using a percent-marker in an arg-call is good.  Imagine you have a standard error-string using `%1` to replace the "where" and `%2` to replace "what" - now in some cases you simply replace "where" with a string, in others you'd like a number.  In case of the string you'd maybe want to put apostrophes around it, in case of a number a hashtag in front would be good to improve readability.  Now you can use the 1st arg-call to replace `%1` with f.e. `"#%3"` and a 3rd arg-call to insert the number.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See the Qt docs about [QString::arg()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg-2):

```
QString str;
str = "%1 %2";
str.arg("%1f", "Hello"); // returns "%1f Hello"
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! And how to deal with the case that you need different overloads of `QString::arg()`, e.g. for numbers as well? Using `QString::number()` in the multi-QString-`arg()` is not the same thing as it doesn't give you the possibility to specify the field width.

Comment: Ok, I could use `QString::leftJustified()` or `QString::rightJustified()`, but this gets lengthy. I think having an automatically escaping version of `arg()` would be great.

Comment: @Johnny, `QString("%1-%2").arg("%1").arg(23, 8, 10, QChar('0'));` will make `QString("00000023-%2")` instead of `QString("%1-00000023")`.

Comment: @Tilman, what do you think about this: QString("%1-%2").arg("%1", QString("%1").arg(23, 8, 10, QChar('0'))); ?

Comment: @Johnny, yeah, not totally terrible ;-) Still sad, it doesn't work in the original elegance... One way would be to escape all % in substitutions and replace them back once the arg() shower has stopped, using some intermediate string-template class. Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 9):

Note that the `arg()` overload for multiple arguments only takes QString. In case not all the arguments are QStrings, you could change the order of the placeholders in the format string:

```
QString("1%1 2%2 3%3 4%4").arg(int1).arg(string2).arg(string3).arg(int4);
```

becomes

```
QString("1%1 2%3 3%4 4%2").arg(int1).arg(int4).arg(string2, string3);
```

That way, everything that is not a string is replaced first, and then all the strings are replaced at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

You should try using

```
QString("%1-%2").arg("%2","foo");
```